# Multiple definition of <List of functions>

Tags: c++

I'm sure that the answer is staring me straight in the face, but I haven't been able to make any progress due to this... First some code:

**objects/testObject.h:**

```
#include <irrlicht.h>
#include "../maths.h"

using namespace irr;

#ifndef testObject_H
#define testObject_H

class testObject : public scene::SAnimatedMesh
{
    public:
        testObject(IrrlichtDevice* device);
        virtual ~testObject();
    protected:
        const char* meshInfoLocation;
        int totAnims;
    private:

};

#endif
```

**objects/testObject.cpp:**

```
#include "testObject.h"

testObject::testObject(IrrlichtDevice* device) : scene::SAnimatedMesh()
{
    io::IrrXMLReader* modelInformation = io::createIrrXMLReader(meshInfoLocation);

    while(modelInformation->read())
    {
        if(modelInformation->getNodeName() == "totAnims") totAnims = stringToInt(modelInformation->getAttributeValue("totAnims"));
    }
}

testObject::~testObject() { } //Incomplete, but should still compile...
```

When I compile this code, I get the following errors:

```
/home/david/workspace/spaceSim/objects/testObject.cpp||In constructor ‘testObject::testObject(irr::IrrlichtDevice*)’:|
/home/david/workspace/spaceSim/objects/testObject.cpp|20|warning: comparison with string literal results in unspecified behaviour [-Waddress]|
/home/david/workspace/spaceSim/main.cpp||In function ‘int main(int, char**)’:|
/home/david/workspace/spaceSim/main.cpp|24|warning: ‘virtual bool irr::io::IFileSystem::addZipFileArchive(const c8*, bool, bool)’ is deprecated (declared at /home/david/irrlicht-1.8.1/include/IFileSystem.h:228) [-Wdeprecated-declarations]|
/home/david/workspace/spaceSim/objects/testObject.cpp||In constructor ‘testObject::testObject(irr::IrrlichtDevice*)’:|
/home/david/workspace/spaceSim/objects/testObject.cpp|20|warning: comparison with string literal results in unspecified behaviour [-Waddress]|
obj/Debug/objects/testObject.o||In function `testObject::testObject(irr::IrrlichtDevice*)':|
/home/david/workspace/spaceSim/objects/testObject.cpp|3|multiple definition of `testObject::testObject(irr::IrrlichtDevice*)'|
obj/Debug/main.o:/home/david/workspace/spaceSim/objects/testObject.cpp|3|first defined here|
obj/Debug/objects/testObject.o||In function `testObject::testObject(irr::IrrlichtDevice*)':|
/home/david/workspace/spaceSim/objects/testObject.cpp|3|multiple definition of `testObject::testObject(irr::IrrlichtDevice*)'|
obj/Debug/main.o:/home/david/workspace/spaceSim/objects/testObject.cpp|3|first defined here|
obj/Debug/objects/testObject.o||In function `testObject::~testObject()':|
/home/david/workspace/spaceSim/objects/testObject.cpp|27|multiple definition of `testObject::~testObject()'|
obj/Debug/main.o:/home/david/workspace/spaceSim/objects/testObject.cpp|27|first defined here|
obj/Debug/objects/testObject.o||In function `testObject::~testObject()':|
/home/david/workspace/spaceSim/objects/testObject.cpp|27|multiple definition of `testObject::~testObject()'|
obj/Debug/main.o:/home/david/workspace/spaceSim/objects/testObject.cpp|27|first defined here|
obj/Debug/objects/testObject.o||In function `virtual thunk to testObject::~testObject()':|
/home/david/workspace/spaceSim/objects/testObject.cpp|29|multiple definition of `virtual thunk to testObject::~testObject()'|
obj/Debug/main.o:/home/david/workspace/spaceSim/objects/testObject.cpp|29|first defined here|
obj/Debug/objects/testObject.o||In function `testObject::~testObject()':|
/home/david/workspace/spaceSim/objects/testObject.cpp|27|multiple definition of `testObject::~testObject()'|
obj/Debug/main.o:/home/david/workspace/spaceSim/objects/testObject.cpp|27|first defined here|
obj/Debug/objects/testObject.o||In function `virtual thunk to testObject::~testObject()':|
/home/david/workspace/spaceSim/objects/testObject.cpp|29|multiple definition of `virtual thunk to testObject::~testObject()'|
obj/Debug/main.o:/home/david/workspace/spaceSim/objects/testObject.cpp|29|first defined here|
||=== Build finished: 14 errors, 3 warnings ===|
```

I've tried the following at solving:

- Combining the header and the cpp files.
- Emptying out all the method bodies and removing the #includes so that all that matters is the class structure.
- Google searches (without any luck...)

Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I compiled your code using gcc4.8.1 from mingw32 (www.mingw.org) (putting them into file, and replacing missing types). The compilation seems to be OK. I guess the problem could be

```
#include <irrlicht.h>
#include "../maths.h"
```

code:

```
//#include <irrlicht.h>
//#include "../maths.h"

//using namespace irr;

#ifndef testObject_H
#define testObject_H
#include <tuple>
namespace scene {
  typedef  std::tuple<int,int> SAnimatedMesh;
};
typedef int IrrlichtDevice;

class testObject : public scene::SAnimatedMesh
{
    public:
        testObject(IrrlichtDevice* device);
        virtual ~testObject();
    protected:
        const char* meshInfoLocation;
        int totAnims;
    private:

};

#endif

//#include "testObject.h"

testObject::testObject(IrrlichtDevice* device) : scene::SAnimatedMesh()
{
  /*
    io::IrrXMLReader* modelInformation = io::createIrrXMLReader(meshInfoLocation);

    while(modelInformation->read())
    {
        if(modelInformation->getNodeName() == "totAnims") totAnims = stringToInt(modelInformation->getAttributeValue("totAnims"));
    }
  */
}

testObject::~testObject() { } //Incomplete, but should still compile...

int main() {}
```